# Online - DispForm with data from another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm using SharePoint online.

I've an "Address Book" list with several name. I have also a "Order list" where I have a lookup colum. This column is looking in the "Title" column of the "Address book" list.

I would like to create a view (maybe using the DispForm, but also another solution would be fine), when an user clicks on the name (Title) in "Address book", the page displayed after the click contains not only the details of the contact, but also the "Orders" made by this user.

Is it possible to do this?

Should I use SharePoint Designer (I checked it quickly but it seems editable only using code and it doesn't seem easy)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create "**Connected Web parts**". Then you can select an item in the MASTER and show thee details in another webpart.

This blog explains how you can do it:
[Creating Connected Web parts in SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rajbugga/2013/04/25/creating-connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint/)

Sample images from this post:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this without SharePoint Designer. Assuming your relationship field is on the child (Orders has a lookup pointing to Address book), you'd do the following:

1. Visit the display form of any record in the address book
2. Click Cog -> Edit Page
3. Go to Insert -> Related Lists -> Select Orders list
4. Drop this related webpart onto the desired part of the page (likely below the details webpart)

What you're doing above is editing the properties page for all addresses, so again, it doesn't matter what record you use when browsing to it.

Cheers,
Matt